# Search fields using criteria and, else, and like

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need a command in vba that will search my [parts name list] table from a form that is bound to my [purchase orders list] table

both tables have [part name] and on the [part name list] table it is never duplicated

---- i need to search for an operation ----

operations are stored in 6 different fields in the [parts name list] , [OP1], [OP2], ect

the purchase order form has 9 keywords represented by check boxes , every OP should have one of those exact keywords in it and in a few cases a part can have multiple instances of it, for example some of my parts require sawing more than once so i will need to return both of those

Answer (score 0):

I'm not complete sure I understand what you're asking, but this might start you off:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim strWHERE As String
Dim strSQL As String

strWHERE = ""

For i = 1 To 9
   If Me("OP" & i) = True Then
      strWHERE = strWHERE & "'" & Me("OP" & i).Tag & "',"
   End If
Next i

If strWHERE <> "" Then
    strWHERE = Left(strWHERE, Len(strWHERE) - 1)
    strSQL = "SELECT OP1 AS Operation FROM [part name list] WHERE OP1 IN (" & strWHERE & ") " & _
        "UNION SELECT OP2 AS Operation FROM [part name list] WHERE OP2 IN (" & strWHERE & ") " & _
        "UNION SELECT OP3 AS Operation FROM [part name list] WHERE OP3 IN (" & strWHERE & ") " & _
        "UNION SELECT OP4 AS Operation FROM [part name list] WHERE OP4 IN (" & strWHERE & ") " & _
        "UNION SELECT OP5 AS Operation FROM [part name list] WHERE OP5 IN (" & strWHERE & ") " & _
        "UNION SELECT OP6 AS Operation FROM [part name list] WHERE OP6 IN (" & strWHERE & ")"
    'open recordset
End If
```

This will get you all operations that match one of the selected keywords on the purchase order.  Without a sample output it's hard to tell if that's what you need.

If you need to match on [part name] you can include that in the WHERE criteria as well.